# How to make a JTextArea scrollable but still have a height set?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, height, jtextarea

I have a Java application that connects to a device and shows the log in a `JTextArea`. I want the `JTextArea` to be scrollable, which I have achieved by putting it inside a `JScrollPane`. The `JScrollPane` containing the `JTextArea` is in the `CENTER` part of a `BorderLayout`. I use `pack()` to set the `JFrame`'s size just before it is shown. However, this has some problems:

- With no height set for the `JTextArea` it is very thin, and the text can't be seen very well (in the second picture there is actually text):

  [image: with no text & no height set] [image: with some text & no height set]
- With a preferred size set for the `JTextArea` it seems to work fine at first. But when there is more text the scrollbars do not appear as expected. They appear when the `JFrame` is resized down regardless of the amount of text in the `JTextArea`. This also doesn't show all the text via scrolling.

  [image: with little text & preferred height] [image: with lots of text & preferred height] [image: with lots of text & preferred height & resized]
- Also, setting a minimum height doesn't help; it leads to the same result as in the first case.

**My code for initializing the frame:**

```
JButton connectBtn, disconnectBtn;
JTextArea logArea;

public MyApplication() throws HeadlessException {
    super();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new MyWindowListener()); // Disconnect and exit on close
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    connectBtn = new JButton("Connect");
    disconnectBtn = new JButton("Disconnect");
    disconnectBtn.setEnabled(false);
    connectBtn.addActionListener(new ConnectListener()); // Connects to device
    disconnectBtn.addActionListener(new DisconnectListener()); // Disconnects from device
    logArea = new JTextArea();
    logArea.setEditable(false);

    // Whatever fixes the problem goes here... e.g.
    // logArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 200));

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    buttons.add(connectBtn, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    buttons.add(disconnectBtn, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(new JScrollPane(logArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't play with the sizes.

Specify the rows/column that you want in the text area and the text area will calculate its own preferred size.

```
//logArea = new JTextArea();
logArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```